# StoppedReason in ECS Fargate is truncated

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

In ECS Fargate, when a task fails, there is a "Stopped Reason" field which gives some useful logging. However I have noticed that it gets truncated after 255 symbols (screenshot below).

I checked the network tab and tracked the JSON of the http response, and it is truncated even there (so server-side). Is there any way to get the complete message?

I find this [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/gmqgo9/ecs_fargate_problem_stoppedreason_cuts_off/) where they discuss the same problem.

How can I see the whole, untruncated error message?

[image]

Comment: Did you try AWS CLI: `aws ecs describe-tasks  --cluster  <cluster> --tasks <task ID>`?

Comment: What do you want to do? How do you use ssm in your ECS?

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question and added what I want to do.

Comment: @sashoalm Did you check if the field is also truncated in AWS ECS events?
see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_cwe_events.html#ecs_task_events --> "The underlying container instance is stopped or terminated."
Technically it says "The detail section below resembles the ContainerInstance object that is returned from a DescribeContainerInstances API operation" but I didn't check this out though.

Comment: Thank you all. I found the whole error message in CloudTrail eventually. I searched by "Username", and entered the Task GUID as username. This narrowed down the amount of events I had to sift through. The full error message was in an "GetParameters" event.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the whole error message in CloudTrail eventually. I searched by "Username", and entered the Task GUID as username. This narrowed down the amount of events I had to sift through. The full error message was in a "GetParameters" event.

> Just FYI for anyone who reads this answer the task GUID is the ID at the end of the taskArn or if you go to Task in the console it will be the ID that you see in Task : fc0398a94d8b4d4d9218a6d870914a80 –
> Emmanuel N K
> Jun 21 at 13:21

Comment: Just FYI for anyone who reads this answer the task GUID is the ID at the end of the `taskArn` or if you go to Task in the console it will be the ID that you see in `Task : fc0398a94d8b4d4d9218a6d870914a80`

Comment: Wow I would NEVER have tried that, thanks a lot, found what I needed!!

Comment: In my case, I got this error: `CannotPullContainerError: inspect image has been retried 5 time(s): httpReaderSeeker: failed open: unexpected status code https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/<image-name>/manifests/sha256:5c72e0e669ae6fe69faf6386543925ff1a6ce3af2eedacdd9...`
Doing the above way just give me a `GetAuthorizationToken` event with the task ID as `User name`, with no useful information.