# AWS Fargate "CannotPullContainerError failed to extract layer"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

I'm attempting to start an ECS Task using an image in our ECR yet it doesn't start, I get the below error:

> CannotPullContainerError: containerd: pull command failed:
> time="2021-08-10T13:12:24Z" level=info msg="apply failure, attempting
> cleanup" error="failed to extract layer
> sha256:e5b96[snip]8caa:
> link /var/...

All other examples of this error online seem to have a 'not found' element to them.. mine doesn't and I'm kind of lost for why it isn't working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it EC2 or fargate lunch type, and is your cluster deployed on private or public subnet?

Comment: Things to check: 1. Does the ECS task have IAM permission to pull the image from ECR? 2. Does the ECS task have a NAT Gateway, or VPC Private Link, to provide network access to the ECR repository? 3. Is there anything wrong with the image in ECR? You could try pulling it to your local computer from ECR to validate this.

Comment: Also, how large is the image? The "failed to extract layer" error almost sounds like a "out of space" error.

Comment: It's a fargate launch type, with a public subnet I believe. The image is 1353MB. I can pull it to my local computer no problem at all.

Comment: You might check for the full (non-truncated) error message in CloudTrail which may give more insight into the problem, per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66919512/stoppedreason-in-ecs-fargate-is-truncated

Comment: CloudTrail doesn't give me any more info. It just shows me calls to GetAuthorizationToken, BatchGetImage, and GetDownloadUrlForLayer loads of times. None of them have any errors in.

Comment: @MarkB any other ideas?

Comment: In my case fargate container runtime_platform  is not correct. I pass WINDOWS_SERVER_2019_CORE then it working

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that this is caused as I was trying to run a Windows container in Fargate, and that apparently isn't supported:

> Windows containers are only supported for tasks that use the EC2 launch type. The Fargate launch type isn't currently supported for Windows containers.

Quote from: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_Windows.html

Comment: 2022 July- is this still true?  And would it not be nice if AWS would tell us this rather than the cryptic error message?

Comment: Looks like Fargate supports Windows as of Oct 2021 
 https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/10/aws-fargate-amazon-ecs-windows-containers/